# c++ Открытие файла в констукторе класса и закрытие в деструкторе?

Tags: c++, файлы

Есть класс Database. Работает с бинарными файлами. Основные методы читают, записывают, читают/записывают данные в файл база данных. 
Как правильно:

1 Открывать в констукторе, закрывать в дестукторе.-
Тогда, как я понимаю, нужно также в конце методов осуществлять какой-то контроль(какой?).

2 Открывать и закрывать в каждом методе.-
Мне кажется, что постоянно открывать/закрывать файл неэффективно. Я прав? И почему так?.

Comment: Зависит от того, как часто вам нужен файл. Если с ним ведется активная работа - то лучше открывать и держать открытым. В методах - обычная проверка успешности операции, ну а как-то восстанавливаться, генерировать исключение или закрывать программу :) - это уже смотрите сами. Ну, еще я бы в методах - если это важно - сбрасывал буферы на диск.

Comment: Открывать в конструкторе (или в отдельной функции) один раз, закрывать в отдельной функции (которая может завершаться ошибкой / кидать исключения) до вызова деструктора, в деструкторе проверять, что закрыто и прибивать программу, если нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мне кажется, что постоянно открывать/закрывать файл неэффективно.

Да, это неэффективно.

> Я прав?

Вы правы.

> И почему так?

Потому, что этот мир жесток и бесчеловечен. На открытие-закрытие файла тратится драгоценное время, отпущенное нам Создателем. Поэтому рекомендуется один раз открыть файл, а в конце работы с файлом закрыть этот файл. Но это тоже не догма. Например, если другие пользователи должны одновременно работать с файлом, то так делать нельзя и придется открывать-закрывать файл в каждом методе. Это медленнее. К тому же это нудно реализовывать. К счастью, в С++ это можно реализовать в виде класса-функционального замыкания.

Еще пример - если открыть 100500 (очень много) файлов, то исчерпается таблица открытых дескрипторов в ОС. К примеру, в приснопамятной DOS по умолчанию можно было открыть одновременно только 15 файлов и таблица дескрипторов была частью исполняемого екзкшника. В современных ОС эта таблица большая, но ведь можно зациклить открытие файла и переполнить любую таблицу...